# Grandkids Deleted files

Tags: internet-connection

My grand kids deleted some files from the Local Area  connection properties box there are 3 missing that I can tell, going by my other computer they are 
Qos Packet Scheduler
Broadcom Advance
Server Program Driver
Can I copy there from somewhere and put them back on the computer as I am unable to connect to my wifi internet any more.

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?, Are you able to see any wifi devices to connect in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that the grandkids deleted any files related to this;  the LAN Connection Properties box deos not represent specific files in that way.  But if you are concerned, simply re-install your Broadcom card driver.  Depending on the make/model of computer, the files could already be present to re-install, or you could download from the computer mfr's website (i.e. Dell, HP, IBM, etc.)  by using your machine's service code or tag.

If that doesn't work or apply, find the model of network card and re-download the driver from Broadcom.  If you are in Windows 7, click on the round button in the bottom left, and choose Control Panel from the pop-up menu.  Make sure you have "View by" (top right) set to "small icons". Choose System. Click on Device Manager near the top left.  Go down to "Network Adapters" and click on the triangle to expand it.  Look for "Broadcom" and see what model of network card it shows.

Then go to the Broadcom site to download the driver (again, assuming you can't get it from the computer-maker's site, which is preferable). http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php

The installation or update of network card drivers is very easy.

The other computer may have different items shown in "Properties" for the LAN Connection, because it has a different network card;  they're not all identical.

Is there a reason that you think the grandkids deleted files?  i.e. have you had network-related problems?